# Saving Image To Custom Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I have an App which stores images  to Custom Library in Photo Album in iphone.

I called the following Function of ALAssetLibrary

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
{
    //write the image data to the assets library (camera roll)
    [self writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation 
                        completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {

                          //error handling
                          if (error!=nil) {
                              completionBlock(error);
                              return;
                          }

                          //add the asset to the custom photo album
                          [self addAssetURL: assetURL 
                                    toAlbum:albumName 
                        withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];

                      }];
}
```

in my SaveImage IBAction

```
-(IBAction)saveToLib:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *savedImage = imgPicture.image;
    NSLog(@"Saved Image%@",savedImage);
    [self.library saveImage:savedImage toAlbum:@"Touch Code" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
}
```

but my application keep getting Crashed
Help me out 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: on statement proceeding NSLog

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: please tell your full crash log...

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ALAssetsLibrary saveImage:toAlbum:withCompletionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8eafb60'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9742/discussion-between-aravindhanarvi-and-addicted)

Comment: I have a same problem. How about a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not calling the [self.library saveImage:savedImage toAlbum:@....] correctly. If you are following this [web site](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/), add #import "ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h" in your view controller.

Not sure if it is the problem. Sorry if this workaround is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the file from the website he downloaded.

I had the same issue and rewriting the code myself solved this.

Maybe encoding or something like this...